# Here SDK: Offline capabilities in Flutter application

Tags: here-api

We have to develop a Flutter application with your SDK, however, we must allow the use of your SDK in offline mode. Unfortunately, the **premium** version is not yet developed for Flutter. What do you think is the best approach to allow using offline mode on a Flutter project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our 4.x SDKs are currently in active development. Offline mode including map, positioning, routing etc has been planned for the 4.x SDKs. Some of the modules will be available in the upcoming releases. So, please check back later for the update.

Comment: Hello, you talk about the SDK Premium for Flutter?

Comment: There is no "Premium" for Flutter. A HERE Flutter SDK is available for the Explore Edition & the Navigate Edition. Both editions allow to cache map data that can be used offline. However, pre-downloading data for offline use is not yet available.