# Here SDK - Android Explore Edition - Offline mode still forecasted?

Tags: android, here-api

At the moment, the Explore edition doesn't allow to find routes or geocoding in offline mode. Only the Navigate version does but it's difficult or not possible to get it for a personal use.

Is it planned to include the offline mode in the Explore edition? It seems that was forecasted when reading this question: [Here SDK: Offline capabilities in Flutter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915198/here-sdk-offline-capabilities-in-flutter-application/62929345#62929345)?

Comment: Did you try reaching out to Here directly?  They would be the only authoritative source.

Comment: Yes, I tried 2 times since last August. Unfortunately, I didn't receive any reply. So, I try with stackoverflow because It seems that some replies to Here-api questions are coming from Here.

Answer (score 0):

the offline functionality is only available on Navigate Edition and until now there is no plan to add it to Explore Edition.

We will share with you a link to the list of products, where you will see all the differences every SDK contains.

https://developer.here.com/products/here-sdk

Comment: Thanks. I know the differences between the versions and it's a pity that there is no longer a possibility to use the offline mode if we have no commercial use. I'm a simple developer and I use an application made with the Here sdk for my personal use. It seems that I will be not able to use it...

Comment: I have a developer account used for the Premium version but I was not registered in the HERE platform. That may be the reason why I didn't receive any reply. Now, I have a platform account and have asked credentials for the Navigate version. I hope that is free for my very limited usage...